# How to send an email from an HTML Elementor form

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I created a form using the HTML Snippets component from Elementor in Wordpress, and now i want to send the data to another .php file to send an email with it, but Wordpress keeps telling me the following:

> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\personalpage\wp-content\send-email.php**

Any other way i can send an email with the form data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create your custom shortcode in your child theme file *functions.php*

```
<?php
add_shortcode('my_form', 'my_form_callback'); // Use this sortcode in your WordPress page
function my_form_callback($atts) {

    return '
      <form action="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $atts['link'].'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input>
        ...
      </form>';
}
```

Then use your shortcode `[my_form link="/send-email.php"]`, your file *send-email.php* should be in the same paste of *functions.php* or edit the `action="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $atts['link'].'"` removing and insert the correct local.